# Retrieving LookupValue of ListItem in SharePoint 2013 Client API

Tags: list, item, client

I'm trying to retrieve the LookupValue of a List item but am unable to do so. I have only seen solutions for SharePoint Server, but none for SharePoint Client.

How can it be done?

Comment: Can you post relevant code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using CAML query**

You can join the lookup list, something like below

```
var query = '<View>' +
    '<Joins>' +
    '<Join Type=\'INNER\' ListAlias=\'Country\'>' +
    '<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Ctry\' RefType=\'Id\' /><FieldRef List=\'Country\' Name=\'ID\'/></Eq>' +
    '</Join>' +
    '</Joins>'+
    '<ProjectedFields>' +
    '<Field Name=\'CtryCountryName\' Type=\'Lookup\' List=\'Country\' ShowField=\'CountryName\' />' +
    '<Field Name=\'CountryContinent\' Type=\'Lookup\' List=\'Country\' ShowField=\'Country_x0020_Continent\' />' +
    '</ProjectedFields>' +
    '</View>';
```

In the above example, `Country` is the parent list.

**Using Client Object Model**

```
var currentItem = itemsEnumerator.get_current();
var myId = currentItem.get_item('FIELD').get_lookupId();
var myTitle = currentItem.get_item('FIELD').get_lookupValue();
```

Comment: @Adrian you asked about how to read LookupValue of a list item. How the answer will become irrelevant?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.
What I meant was, in relevance of this question, can we have a private chat? Thank you (That was typed incorrectly, my apologies).

Comment: OK you can invite me to a chat room